# How do I make a float only show a certain amount of decimals

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a float that has 16 decimal places, but I want it to be capped at 6, and if I ever get a float that has less than 6 decimals, I want it to add 0s until it has 6.
i.e.:

> 1.95384240549 = 1.953842
> 3.12 = 3.120000

I'm trying to generate a value based on a certain amount of demand an object has. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To round to a certain amount of decimals you can use `round()`

#### Example:

```
round(1.95384240549,6) > 1.953842
```

And for more 0's after the decimal place you can use `format()`:

```
format(3.12, '.6f') > '3.120000'
```

*Note this is of type string*

Read more here:

[Rounding syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round)

[Format syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format)

Comment: No need to use `round` if you're going to do custom formatting anyway.  And the only way to get trailing zeros is with a string, so you'll need to use `format`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complex than the previous answer, but more consistent.

```
import math

def truncate(number, digits) -> float:
    places = len(str(number)[str(number).find("."):])
    if places > 6:
        stepper = 10.0 ** digits
        return math.trunc(stepper * number) / stepper
    else:
        return str(number) + "0"*(6 - places)
```

Examples: `truncate(3.12 , 6)` returns `3.120000` and `truncate(1.95384240549, 6)` returns  `1.953842`