# Dynamic decimal point Python float

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to neatly show rounded floats of varying decimal lengh.

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
In: 0.0000000071234%
Out: 0.0000000071%

In: 0.00061231999999%
Out: 0.0061%

In: 0.149999999%
Out: 0.15%
```

One way to do it would be:

```
def dynamic_round(num):
    zeros = 2
    original = num
    while num< 0.1:
        num*= 10
        zeros += 1
    return round(original, zeros)
```

I'm sure however there is a much cleaner way to do the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a float only show a certain amount of decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782367/how-do-i-make-a-float-only-show-a-certain-amount-of-decimals)

Comment: The last example (.1499999) isn't rounding. Are you certain that's the correct output?

Comment: Roy2012 you're right, typo on my part. Fixed.

Comment: You might consider using Decimals instead of floats: `from decimal import Decimal`

Comment: @MindaugasM, it will be good if you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answer which helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without a loop:

```
a = 0.003123
log10 = -int(math.log10(a))
res = round(a, log10+2)

==> 0.0031
```

Comment: Using a variable named `ln` for a base 10 logarithm is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Btw, there's `log10()`

Comment: Both are fair comments. Updated the answer.

Comment: Using the name of a function for a variable is even worse.

Comment: @Roy2012, it will be good to put all this into a single expression: `res = round(a, -int(math.log10(a)) + 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This post answers your question with a similar logic
[How can I format a decimal to always show 2 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)
but just to clarify

One way would be to use **round()** function also mentioned in the documentation
[built-in functions: round()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfWLi.png)

```
>>> round(number[,digits])
```

here digit refers to the precision after decimal point and is optional as well.

Alternatively, you can also use [new format specifications](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
>>> from math import pi  # pi ~ 3.141592653589793
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(pi)
'3.14'
```

here the number next to f tells the precision and f refers to float.

Another way to go here is to **import numpy**

```
>>>import numpy
>>>a=0.0000327123
>>>res=-int(numpy.log10(a))
>>>round(a,res+2)
>>>0.000033
```

numpy.log() also, takes an array as an argument, so if you have multiple values you can iterate through the array.

Comment: Figuring out the number of digits to round or format is crucial, and you don't touch on that at all.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Updated.

Comment: @ghost_ds, are there any difference in `log10()` functions from `numpy` and from `math`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght `numpy.log()` is actually faster than `math.log()` and secondly, you can also pass an array for multiple values at once in `numpy.log()` which is not possible in the `math.log()`.